# How to check if comma list is empty?

Tags: conditionals, expl3, latex3, comma-separated-list

How do I check if `\myList` is empty? Following (is my attempt) prints "NOT empty" when, in fact, the list is empty.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \clist_new:N\myList
  \clist_set:Nn\myList{}
  \cs_if_eq:NNTF\myList{}{EMPTY}{NOT empty}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I found a way to do so (below) but would like you to share another approach (it's interesting to see how else it can be done):

```
  \clist_new:N\myList
  \clist_new:N\emptyList
  \clist_set:Nn\myList{} % assign "emptiness" to the list (although it had already been empty to begin with)
  \cs_if_eq:NNTF\myList\emptyList{EMPTY}{NOT empty}
```

Comment: `\clist_if_empty:NTF`.

Comment: What Ulrike said, plus the “proper” way to make a `clist` empty is `\clist_clear:N \myList`. (Deep down is basically the same, but exist for semantics).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N\myList
\clist_set:Nn\myList{}
\clist_if_empty:NTF \myList{ EMPTY }{ NOT EMPTY }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

run `texdoc l3clist`

Comment: How can I use AND (&&) during this `\clist_if_empty` check to also perform check on additional list (or on something else) in one directive?

Comment: See `\bool_if:nTF` or (better) e.g. `\bool_lazy_or:nnTF`, all in `interface3`.

Comment: @bp2017 You can always use the `c`-type variants, e..g `\clist_new:c { myList2 }`. Note though that there is no escaping the catcode and token basis of TeX. Also note that standard `expl3` style would be `\l_bp_mylist_clist` or similar.

Comment: @bp2017 You want the predicates: `\clist_if_empty_p:N`, and so on

Answer (score 9):

The test you want is `\clist_if_empty:N(TF)`: each data type has an appropriate test for emptiness or similar. These are defined such that they are 'aware' of the internal nature of data types (for example an empty `prop` is not entirely empty at the macro level).

Your `\cs_if_empty:NN(TF)` test is *wrong* as the second argument you have given is no `N` type (a single token), but is rather `n`-type (in this case, an empty token list). You could in this case do a low-level test, for example

```
\cs_if_eq:NN(TF) \myList \c_empty_clist { <true> } { <false> }
```

or by expanding the list to a 'raw' token list

```
\tl_if_blank:V(TF) \c_empty_clist { <true> } { <false> }
```

Comment: There is a style in `tikzset` named `myStyle`, I tried to pass `#1` of that style (which contains all the arguments passed to the style, supplied through a node or a path directive which calls that style with or without arguments) inside `/utils/exec` as `\clist_set:Nn\myList{#1}`. But for some reason when the style is used with no arguments (like `\path node[myStyle];`), the list is NOT empty (it's empty only when `\path node[myStyle={}];`). I'm trying to figure out why I get such result (and trying to look what `#1` contains in this case, but having difficulties so far).

Comment: @bp2017 There is some 'back end' in `pgf` that may be responsible, but I'd be tempted just to `\showtokens` the input `#1`.

Comment: @bp2017: `myStyle` is internally replaced with `mystyle=\pgfkeysnovalue`. You can provide a different default value, however. See section 87.3.2 of the `pgf` manual.